# calculate the Ranking of questionnaire

Tags: mysql

I am trying to develop a ranking table for a sort of questionnaire.

Each day a question is asked at 16h (4:00 pm), which can be answered by 17:59:59 the following day. The table has to show the position of the participants taking into account the correct answers is the time.

My table will be of the sort:

```
+-------+---------+---------------------+
|userid | correct |      timestamp      |
+-------+---------+---------------------+
|   2   |    1    | 2018-02-07 16:00:01 |
|   1   |    1    | 2018-02-07 16:02:00 |
|   3   |    1    | 2018-02-07 17:00:00 |
|   1   |    0    | 2018-02-08 16:00:02 |
|   3   |    1    | 2018-02-08 16:00:05 |
|   2   |    0    | 2018-02-08 16:01:00 |
+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

For now I started with this query:

```
SELECT `userid`, `correct `, `timestamp`, 
count(correct) as count 
FROM `results` 
WHERE correct = 1
GROUP BY `userid `
ORDER BY count DESC, timestamp DESC
```

But I have already realized that this is not what I intend because the ranking has to be cumulative but taking into account the several days.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

A user from Stackoverflow Portugal advised this code but it is not working either.

```
SELECT userid, SUM(correct),
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,(timestamp,CAST(CONCAT_WS(' ',date(timestamp), '17:59:59') as DATETIME)))) time
FROM results
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY correct DESC, time
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Would you need a resulting query to contain only the userid and count?

Comment: is not what I intend because the result has to take into account whether answering all the right tips.
You can see the result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15afab

Answer (score 0):

Don’t deal with this datetime (16h), this may be changed and you will be lost on your query.
Instead, you should count by userid and questionnaire_id. To do so:

- add new table questionnaire [id, title] (you can add extra column
  later : created_time, end_time, …)
- edit your record table by adding the questionnaire id as FK : [userid, questionnaireid, correct, timestamp]

then count normally: **Correct answer by user, by questionnaire**

```
SELECT userid, questionnaireid , 
sum(correct) as total 
FROM results r
INNER JOIN questionnaire q
ON r.questionnaireid = q.id
WHERE correct = 1
GROUP BY userid, questionnaireid
ORDER BY total DESC, id ASC
```

Comment: it must be possible to answer each question for 24h, starting at 4pm each day, after that time a new question comes in. I can not change that.

Comment: I know the current requirement is that, but I suggested you calculate by questionnaire not by 'time' (more cleaner as a model)